# Range based for loop for heap allocated arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Consider the following code which will cout `success` exactly three times:

```
int arr [3];

for(int& value : arr )
    std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
```

If I try to allocate array on the heap, there are problem. This code doesn't compile:

```
int* ptr = new int[3];

for(int& value : *ptr )
    std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
```

Since the pointer was dereferenced, the types should be the same. So I have some questions:

- what is the fundamental difference between when I ask from the hardware in the two expressions. I'd like to understand why the latter don't make sense.
- Can I make it work with a small change?

Comment: When you are using heap allocated array, the size information of the array will be lost.

Comment: Re: "will cout `success`" -- `cout` is a noun, not a verb. <g>

Comment: If `range_expression` is a container, it has member `begin` and `end`, otherwise it's a built-in array with call `std::begin(c)`. 
  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A raw array only supports the range-based for syntax if the visible declaration includes the number of elements, i.e. `int arr[3]` in the first case and `int* prt` in the second case. In the first case this is given (but still you should prefer `std::array` if possible), but not in the second case you allocate memory on the heap and the information about the size is gone. You can circumvent this, if you simply use `std::array` rather than the raw array.

> Since the pointer was dereferenced, the types should be the same.

Taking a closer look under the hood, the reason for this is, that in the first case you have an array and in the second case you have a pointer, which is **NOT** even the same type.

This misinterpretation of pointer and array equaliuty keeps to be broadcasted over C++ tutorials, but this is wrong. This might be due to the fact, that when passing an array to a function taking a pointer of that type, the array *decays* to a pointer, known as **array-decay**.

> Can I make it work with a small change

Yes you can. Use `std::array` or `st::vector` which will make it look like that for `std::array`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3>* ptr = new std::array<int, 3>;

    for(int& value : *ptr )
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
}
```

For brevity I did not include the delete for the pointer which you should always do.

However, if you allocate memory on the heap, it is almost always best to use `std::vector` as deallocation will be taken care for automatically. The program would than read:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vecor>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(3);

    for(int& value : vec)
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Since the pointer was dereferenced, the types should be the same.

Take a closer look at the type of the pointer: `int* ptr`. It is a pointer to `int` Compare that to type of `arr` which is `int[3]`. Those types are different. So, your assumption that the types should be same is wrong. `int[3]` is a range, while `int` is not.

The array-new-expression returns a pointer to first element of the array. That is what `ptr` points to. The memory address of the first element is the same as the whole array, but the type of the variable determines how it can be used.

> Can I make it work with a small change?

Since the value of the pointer to the first element is the same as a pointer to the whole array, you can reinterpret the pointer as the other type using a cast:

```
auto arr_ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int (*)[3]>(ptr));
for(int& value : *arr_ptr)
```

That said, typically dynamic arrays are used because they allow the size to be determined at runtime. The size in that cast must be known at compile time.

Furthermore, your example code leaks the array. While the leak is easy to fix in this code, manual memory management is in general difficult, and unnecessary. You're most certainly better off using `std::vector` when you need a dynamic array:

```
std::vector<int> v(3);
for(int& value : v)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not running in UB land with that reinterpret_cast, as you are not casting to char*?

Comment: I am always unsure with reinterpret cast.

Comment: @Pi I can't blame you for that :) I added laundering to the example code just in case.

Comment: If the types are not similar, than std::launder won't help. The outcome as far as I know is still UB.

Comment: It basically breaks down to the question if the array and the pointer are similar. If not, it is UB. But I honestly do not know.

Comment: @Pi I checked the standard, and the conversion is definitely at least unspecified if not UB without laundering. With laundering, I'm not sure either, perhaps we need to post another question. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) uses an equivalent as an example, with comment "OK".

Comment: The other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039886/stdlaunder-in-conjunction-with-reinterpret-cast)

Comment: Esssntially the answer to the new question is: it is valid