# std::launder in conjunction with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

While answering the question "*[Range based for loop for heap allocated arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038186/range-based-for-loop-for-heap-allocated-arrays/52038398?noredirect=1#52038398)*" today I stumbled upon the suggestion to use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to cast from a pointer type to an array-type using [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) (After some discussion we decided to post a new question, as we could not find a conclusion.). The cast was done as follows (lets say, e.g., in order to be able to use range-based loops to iterate over the array):

```
int* ptr = new int[3];
auto arr_ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int (*)[3]>(ptr));
```

I am almost certain this is UB, but I am not really sure. 
Is anyone firm enough in C++ to answer that?

I think this breaks down to the question if `reinterpret_cast` is valid when casting from ptr-type to array-type, which I think is UB, and has nothing to to whether or not I use `std::launder`.

Comment: As far as I understand launder (and the understanding is not that well), it's well defined. But why not do `new int[1][3]` 

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You lost me;) . How would `new int[1][3]` help.

Comment: Please ignore my comment regarding launder.. seeing the examples on cpprefetence about launder, I realize I had no idea about the restrictions of it's applications.

Comment: because it doesn't need the cast

Comment: There is a dupe somewhere. Suffice it to say this snippet is well-formed, but there is an amazing amount of nuance.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#1: "If it is an array, the result of the new-expression is a pointer to the initial element of the array". And then this is a duplicate of what Passer By linked.

Comment: I think that is correct! Thanks for clarifying that for me!